# How to sign out of the Windows 8 Wordament game app so that another person can play with a different account

Tags: windows-8, wordament

I have not been able to find a sign out option in the Windows 8 Wordament game so that another person can log in with a different account.

I tried going to the Games section (from the tile on the Windows 8 home page) & signed in with a different account. However, when I go the Wordament app, the account with which I had originally signed in still shows up.

Can anyone please explain the steps to sign out of the Wordament app so that I can log in with a new gamertag?

Comment: I believe that you have to sign out from the Games app... except that I don't see any obvious way to do so

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Help and Option" within the game and scroll to the bottom. There is a sign out button.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can find on the matter is [this Xbox article](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/Live/ChangeUser).